# html email with link opened with html email off

Tags: html, email, hyperlink

I would like to send an html email with a link but want it to look ok if html is off in the recipients email client how can I do this:

With HTML:
Available  [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/)

With Out HTML:
Available  at https://stackoverflow.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Then use [multipart alternative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME#Alternative) to send a text version alternative to your HTML email that has the full link.

Comment: (If you're using PHP) there are several good html2txt classes that take HTML and make a very decent txt version (incl links and titles etc) to send in your e-mail. All my apps always send html and text. `"Available here"` in HTML would become `"Available here [http://full-URL]"` with html2txt.

Answer (score 1):

You should ensure that your text is readable without css or html formatting (i.e. if you're using tables, make sure the order of the text is ok if you strip the tags, if you use images, use alts)

Use a library such as [SwiftMailer](http://swiftmailer.org/) that will let you add multipart content to an email. It's much easier than setting the headers yourself.